# Ajax response ok in inspector, not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response, inspector

When I make an Ajax call, I can see the correct response value in the browser inspector. But, when I want to use that response in js, I can not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var origin = "US";
        var price = "277";
        var currency = "AED";
        var weight = "500";
        var weightCurrency = "gram";
        var count = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.zakoola.com/order/GetCalculatedPrice",
            type: "Post",
            data: { Origin: origin, Price: price, Currency: currency, Weight: weight, WeightCurrency: weightCurrency, Count: count }
            })
            .done(function (res) {
                $("#price").html(res);
            });
    });
});
```

I have a `h1` tag with the id of `#price` in the html. Besides, instead of changing the `h1` text I tried `alert()` to show the `res` value, but it doesn't work. It seems that response function is never called but I can see the response value in the inspector.

[image]

UPDATE 1:
Console says `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.zakoola.com/order/GetCalculatedPrice. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).` and `.fail` function is being called with the following return: `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}`


UPDATE 2: Only Firefox is showing the response payload correctly. Edge & IE aren't.

Comment: You might consider using ES6 to simplify your object definitions, such as `data: { Origin, Price, Currency, Weight ... }` to reduce syntax noise a bit

Comment: You might be able to circumvent the missing cross origin headers that would allow you to do this by changing the data type of your ajax to JSONP (        `dataType: "jsonp"`) and providing a callback (`jsonpCallback: res => $("#price").html(res)`)

Comment: It's not because you can see the response in the console network inspector that you can access it with XMLHttpRequest/fetch/$.ajax. Firefox will show you the data, but it will obey CORS rules in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the update, you should add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the server you are performing the request. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

> The Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header indicates whether the
>   response can be shared with resources with the given origin.

in that header you should set your origin (http://example.com) or `*`.

If you can't modify backend headers, you can't perform ajax requests in this way.

About browser compatibility see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#Browser_compatibility), then, your Firefox is probably less than 3.5

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with CORS on the api you are using `url: "http://www.zakoola.com/order/GetCalculatedPrice"`, not an AJAX fault. AJAX does not allow the request to proceed, if the origin (your home url) is not specified on your api side. If the server api is being controlled by you, you could try to set all the needed CORS headers in your api.

Comment: Right. but how you explain the correct response payload in firefox? if the destination server refuses my request then how can i have the correct response?

Comment: Because the response of the server itself is correct, so you can fetch the data from that url in your web browser. The problem you're facing appears while you are trying to fetch data with AJAX call, called CORS problem, which means you have to add ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header in your server side, to solve this issue.